# Архитектура сохранения данных, защищенная от изменений

Tags: c#, mvvm, архитектура

Сразу скажу, может есть какая-то литература по этому поводу (должны же быть какие-то общепринятые практики программирования при реализации этой типовой в общем-то задачи). Тогда прошу дать ссылку. Ну либо  посоветуйте свой вариант.

Язык C#, платформа WPF. Использую MVVM.

Хочу разработать формат сохранений для своей программы.

Для этого мне нужно сохранить значения некоторых свойств коллекции объектов. Сами свойства помечены аттрибутом [Controlled]. Они определяют состояние объекта. При восстановлении состояния приложения из сохранения должны быть созданы такие же объекты с сохраненными значениями этих свойств.

Проблема в следующем: простая бинарная или XML сериализация не подходит по той причине, что при простом переименовании свойства или названия класса старые сохранения не откроются.

Придумал следующий выход: назначить для каждого свойства его псевдоним. Но дальше встает вопрос: где лучше хранить взаимосвязи "псевдоним-свойство".

Вижу несколько вариантов:

1. Задать словарь соответствий в конструкторе класса-сериализатора. Плюсы: при переименовании свойств соответствия будут автоматически обновлены IDE (если использовать конструкцию nameof). Минусы: долго и муторно добавлять каждое свойство в соответствующий класс. Плюсы: новый формат сохранения реализуется просто созданием соответствующего класса-наследника, определяющего свою таблицу сериализации.
2. Изменить аттрибут [Controlled] так, чтобы он мог хранить псевдоним [Controlled("Псевдоним свойства")]. Ну либо создать еще один специальный аттрибут. Плюсы: простота. Минусы: информация для сохранения размазывается по всем классам, а не хранится в одном месте. Если будет принято решение разработать новый формат сохранения, то придется добавлять новые атрибуты. Бизнес-логика приложения не должна содержать эту лишнюю информацию (хотя это и атрибуты, но замусоривать код класса посторонней информацией не слишком хорошо).
3. Еще можно для хранения связей свойство объекта - псевдоним использовать локальную БД. Мне даже советовали посмотреть в сторону Entity-Attribute-Value модели. Но тогда нужно и файлы сохранения организовывать как дамп такой БД.
   Но можно использовать таблицы хотя бы внутри самой программы для хранения связей между свойствами и псевдонимами. Плюсы: наглядное хранение всей информации в одном месте. Минусы: при изменении классов придется ручками править данные в базе (или есть варианты?).
4. Обойтись без псевдонимов. Однажды определить свойства и названия классов и никогда больше их не менять. В файл напрямую сохранять названия классов, их свойств и значения этих свойств. При восстановлении проверять, являются ли эти классы разрешенными для создания.
   Плюсы: простота реализации. Для любого класса достаточно просто перебрать все свойства, помеченные как [Controlled] и сохранить их. 
   Минусы: раскрытие деталей реализации программы и отсутствие гибкости (опечатки в названиях классов и свойств придется хранить как зеницу ока, ибо при исправлении старые сохранения не откроются).
5. Использовать вариант 4 с возможностью создания псевдонимов для отдельных свойств и классов. Плюсы: остается возможность переименований. Простота поддержки. Минусы: при изменении имени свойства, для которого не было создано псевдонима, придется определять псевдоним в каждом классе, реализующем формат сохранения.
6. Создать специальные классы для хранения значений свойств объекта. И сериализовывать в XML уже их.
   Плюсы: проще получать значения из готовых классов. Минусы: по-прежнему сохраняется проблема изменений, только уже самих классов, которые будут использоваться для сериализации.

Comment: Вы, конечно, понимаете, что вы можете атрибутами указать как вам надо сериализовать тот или иной тип в xml? Но я бы выделил сохранение и загрузку в отдельные классы, а в них уже сохранял так, как понравится (например, ваш вариант 6)

Comment: При xml-сериализации можно атрибутами задавать любое имя: [Controlling XML Serialization Using Attributes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes). При бинарной сериализации см. [Version tolerant serialization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/version-tolerant-serialization)

Comment: Не знал, или забыл. Про бинарную сериализацию почитал, интересно. Но насколько это хорошо, использовать бинарную сериализацию для сохранений? Не очень бы хотелось принимать от пользователя объекты, ведь "пользователю верить нельзя". Или там с безопасностью все ок?
Про аттрибуты в XML интересно. Правда придется опять-таки сериализовать все классы бизнес-логики. А я не хотел перегружать их сторонним кодом (даже в виде атрибутов). Еще при бинарной сериализации  возникают проблемы с объектами из другой библиотеки, если они не поддерживают сериализацию.

Comment: А вообще, похоже, я действительно так или иначе пытаюсь сделать сериализатор.

Comment: Бинарная сериализация для сохранения не подходит:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization
Binary serialization can be dangerous. Never deserialize data from an untrusted source and never round-trip serialized data to systems not under your control.
А XML-сериализация требует наличия конструкторов без параметров.
Похоже, все-таки свой вариант придется делать.